# Angular2 dependency injection - multiple layer

Tags: dependency-injection, typescript, angular

**See the bottom of this question to see what I had to change to make it work.**

I'm trying to figure out how to inject an object which gets an injection from another file. Following an example from [angular.io 5 Min Quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html) and [Pascal Precht's article about Dependency Injection](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/05/18/dependency-injection-in-angular-2.html), I made my Person2 be injected to main app class successfully.

app.ts:

```
/// <reference path="typings/angular2/angular2.d.ts" />

import {Component, View, bootstrap} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {Person2} from './person2';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app'
})
@View({
    template: '<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>'
})
class MyAppComponent {
    name: string;

    constructor(person: Person2) {
        this.name = person.name;
    }
}

bootstrap(MyAppComponent, [Person2]);
```

person2.ts:

```
export class Person2 {
    name: string;

    constructor() {
        this.name = 'Mee!';
    }
}
```

And that works fine. Now I try to inject Person, which gets Person2.

person.ts:

```
import {Inject} from 'angular2/angular2';

export class Person {
    name: string;

    constructor(@Inject('Person2') person2) {
        this.name = person2.name;
    }
}
```

Couple of notes about person.ts:

1. I couldn't figure out where to get 'angular2/di'. It seems 'angular2/angular2' has Inject since typescript compiler did not complain.
2. [Pascal Precht's article about Dependency Injection](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/05/18/dependency-injection-in-angular-2.html) says I can inject either `@Inject(Person2) Person2` or `person: Person2`, but none of them works since typescript compiler doesn't know where to get Person2 from. So I tried `@Inject('Person2') person2` and at least that gets compiled.
3. person.ts may compile with `person: Person2` only if I import Person2 within person.ts. But I should be able to inject Person2 to Person without importing it within Person. If I have to import what I am injecting, what would be the point of dependency injection, right?

Revised app.ts:

```
/// <reference path="typings/angular2/angular2.d.ts" />

import {Component, View, bootstrap} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {Person} from './person';
import {Person2} from './person2';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app'
})
@View({
    template: '<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>'
})
class MyAppComponent {
    name: string;

    constructor(person: Person) {
        this.name = person.name;
    }
}

bootstrap(MyAppComponent, [Person, Person2]);
```

When I run the revised app, I don't get expected result but get browser console error saying `Error during instantiation of Person! (MyAppComponent -> Person).`

What did I do wrong?

**EDIT**
I tried @alexpods answer but still no luck. I made a [Plunker with compiled js files](http://plnkr.co/edit/j6q4rb4RlvHgUcns5qTt). If you change app.js line #27 to `[person_1.Person]`, you will see it not working anymore.

**EDIT 2: Finally I made it work**

As @alexpods said, I changed the bootstrap line on app.ts and how it gets injected.

```ts
// you need to import Inject and bind
import {Component, View, bootstrap, Inject, bind} from 'angular2/angular2';
//...../.
// you need to inject using @Inject. person: Person will not work.
constructor(@Inject('Person') person) {
//......
// on top of declaring Person and Person2 as dependencies, you need to associate the string `Person` and `Person2` to actual class, so that @Inject can find them.
bootstrap(MyAppComponent, [Person, Person2, bind('Person').toClass(Person), bind('Person2').toClass(Person2)]);
```

And that was still not enough: unlike [angular.io 5 Min Quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html) said, I had to NOT include `--emitDecoratorMetadata`. My tsc command looks like this:

```
tsc --watch -m commonjs -t es5 app.ts person.ts person2.ts --experimentalDecorators
```

Here is [another plunker that works](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZB6Tv9Ak22z4EmubzCWC).

I am using tsc version 1.6.0-beta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add binding for `'Person2'` string to the application `bootstrap` (or to the `MyApComponent` through `bindings` property):

```
import {Component, View, bootstrap, bind } from 'angular2/angular2';

// a lot of code ...

bootstrap(MyAppComponent, [Person, Person2, bind('Person2').toClass(Person2)]);
```

Comment: It looks good, but I think it makes no sense. He can easily do it through `Person`, but well...

Comment: @kennethc I think there is some error with compilation (don't know what one exactly). Check out [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Jgn1wXi5lSHxUR7FbHHt?p=preview). It works.

Comment: @alexpods I really appreciate your time. I still have an issue. Do you mind revising your plunker to have person and person2 classes on separate files, export them, and then inject it from main.es6.js?

Comment: @kennethc [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/cMKmusrpWF2bHv15IK7n?p=preview) is plunker with separate files for person and person2